# "PythonAccumulatorV2 does not exist" - when running SparkContext() within Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, windows, jupyter-notebook, apache-spark-2.0

I recently installed Spark 2.3 on my Windows machine (with Java 8) and was able to run it via Jupyter Notebooks (Python 3).

Suddenly it stopped working - I get below error when trying to instantiate SparkContext within Notebook:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
```

Splitting the code on one-line-per-cell basis shows that it's the 2nd line that causes it.

It seems to be purely Notebook issue, as I'm still able to execute .py files with 'spark-submit' via command line.

Any idea how to fix it?

```
-------------------------------------------------
Py4JError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-57590c71cf44> in <module>()
      1 from pyspark import SparkContext
----> 2 sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
--> 118                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    119         except:
    120             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    186         self._accumulatorServer = accumulators._start_update_server()
    187         (host, port) = self._accumulatorServer.server_address
--> 188         self._javaAccumulator = self._jvm.PythonAccumulatorV2(host, port)
    189         self._jsc.sc().register(self._javaAccumulator)
    190 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1523         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1524         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1525             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1526 
   1527         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    330                 raise Py4JError(
    331                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
--> 332                     format(target_id, ".", name, value))
    333         else:
    334             raise Py4JError(

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had also the same issue. It was basically due to a conflict in the pyspark/spark versions, so please check to the "sub-version" also matches, e.g. v2.3.1 vs v2.3.2

You can use:

> pip install pyspark==2.3.x to get the right version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by updating my `pyspark` to the latest version.